# Time series with additional features

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

**Hello everyone!**
I have dataset that contains columns:

- date
- feature1
- feature2
- Y

I need Y prediction to next several values (date, feature1, feature2).
Y tends to fall over time (maybe exponentially) and Y(date) to some extent is a time series.

It is desirable to obtain a simple model solution based on statistics.
*It is really ? Or for best predictions need use machine learning methods ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "simple model solution based on statistics" may give you the best predictive performance.

You can evaluate and compare different approaches. It's a good idea to start with [naïve baselines](https://otexts.com/fpp2/simple-methods.html), then try out "statistical" models (e.g. Exponential Smoothing, ARIMA or Theta), and finally see if more complicated machine learning models help improve predictive performance.